Scope is marked as succeeded when last action succeeds, even though there was an error in the scope

Summary of what's happening here

Action 1 succeeds
Action 2 fails
Action 3 is skipped because action 2 failed
Action 4 runs after action 3 is skipped (configured that way) and succeeds
Scope 1 is marked as succeeded since the last action succeeded
action 5 is skipped since it's configured to run after scope 1 fails (this is not what I want to happen)

I'm not sure if this was intended by the Logic App engineers, but when the last action in a scope succeeds, then the entire scope is marked as succeeded, even if every other action in that scope fails which imo is not a good design. My goal is to run action 5 if anything in scope 1 fails, but the way logic apps is working thwarts that.
1. What is the reason for why the scope is designed to work like this?
The docs even say

By default, when all the scope's actions succeed, the scope's status is marked Succeeded

source
The keyword there being all. Imo, if the scope action actually worked like that, that would amazing and fix my issue.
2. Do you know another way around this issue so that I can achieve my goal stated above?
Thank you!

I don't fully understand the purpose of configuring action 4 to run only after action 3 has been skipped, if it can only be skipped when action 2 fails.
I would have redesigned the workflow as follows, in which case it works as expected:

